# TypeError: Object of type GetPriceVolumes is not JSON serializable - Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am getting TypeError: Object of type GetPriceVolumes is not JSON serializable when trying to render dashboard using Plotly Dashboard. It seems that I need to serialize jSON which came back from yahoo finance API. How can I do it? Thank you

Full code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


class GetPriceVolumes:

    final_response = []
    data = {}


    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.ticker = ticker,

    ### GET historical data for specific ticker - ie: AAPL ###
    def getSymbolData(self):

        url = "https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-historical-data"

        querystring = {"frequency": "1d", "filter": "history", "period1": "1546448400", "period2": "1591442782",
                       "symbol": self.ticker}

        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-host': "RRRRRRRRRRRR",
            'x-rapidapi-key': "RRRRRRRRRRRR"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        GetPriceVolumes.final_response = response.json()

        return GetPriceVolumes.final_response

    def getConvertDataToJson(self):

        x = GetPriceVolumes.final_response['prices']



        #sample_json = jsonpickle.encode(x)
        GetPriceVolumes.data = x

        print(type(GetPriceVolumes.data))
        print(GetPriceVolumes.data)
        return GetPriceVolumes.data

    def getVolumePriceChart(self):

        df = pd.DataFrame(GetPriceVolumes.data)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')

        fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="close")
        return fig
```

Error: TypeError: Object of type GetPriceVolumes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Are you updating the content of `data` before calling in the following line?
```df = pd.DataFrame(GetPriceVolumes.data)```

Comment: No it is not updated before ```df = pd.DataFrame(GetPriceVolumes.data)```

Comment: Actually I am thinking if ```GetPriceVolumes.data``` and ```GetPriceVolumes.final_response``` are not redundant but w/e for now.

Comment: I tried to improve your formatting, but it tells me `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.` - so this is a recommendation for you.