# Python json TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, boto3

I did check [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309377/typeerror-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable) [of d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278737/object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable)[iffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292622/typeerror-object-of-type-getpricevolumes-is-not-json-serializable-python)[rent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable) [rel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357930/typeerror-object-of-type-function-is-not-json-serializable)[ate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189408/python-typeerror-object-of-type-ndarray-is-not-json-serializable)[d Q'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150304/typeerror-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable-django)[n'A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278737/object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable) (see linked questions), but none adressed my specific problem, mostly it was about different datatypes or requirements.

The attempt is to use this snippet to convert a nested map to json:

```py
import json
#...
result = json.dumps(table_scan)
```

I am aware of [the problems of this working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62095356/4575793), but this doesnt seem to be the problem here. The above unfortunately gives me:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda-function.py", line 61, in lambda_handler
    result
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
```

How can I fix this without having to go into the (quite large) map for a 'manual' conversion.

*(Application context more precisely: My python AWS lambda function performs scanning a DynamoDB with `boto3` which gives me a (multi-layer) [dict≈map](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#defining-a-dictionary). My goal is to convert this map to a json in order to return it (outwards) to a AWS API gateway. The items inside the Database come from the event parameters of the (inwards) API gateway.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **custom encoder** for **specific json values** (including `Decimal`) can be used [as suggested here](https://github.com/open-contracting/spoonbill-web/issues/120). In this example, `Decimal` should presumably be converted to `float`:

```py
import json
from decimal import Decimal

#Does quasi the same things as json.loads from here: https://pypi.org/project/dynamodb-json/
class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

#...
result = json.dumps(table_scan, cls=JSONEncoder)  #Works!
```

Comment: Note that as others have pointed out so well on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678946/python-3-x-cannot-serialize-decimal-to-json there are inaccuracies that can arise from converting a decimal to a float. They suggest using str() rather than float() to avoid losing any precision or creating any rounding errors, which was presumably a reason for using Decimal in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not yet able to post this as a comment.

You can consider [monkey-patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey-patch)ing the missing feature [instead of writing your own JSONEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104541/13914780). To do so, you can (for the sake of simplicity) write an own small standalone module, say `make_json_serializable.py` to apply this monkey patch ([what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-a-monkey-patch)) to the

> json module when it's imported so JSONEncoder.default() automatically checks for a special "to_json()" method and uses it to encode the object if found. (Quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561055/4575793))

Code:

```py
from json import JSONEncoder

def _default(self, obj):
    return getattr(obj.__class__, "to_json", _default.default)(obj)

_default.default = JSONEncoder.default  # Save unmodified default.
JSONEncoder.default = _default # Replace it.
```

Then you can add an `to_json` method to any class like taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764817/4575793):

```py
def to_json(self):
  return float(self) # or how you want it to be serialized
```

Then you also don't have to update every `json.dumps()` in your project [like Onur said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538391/4575793). Applying this monkey-patch should work like this (untested):

```py
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal.to_json = to_json
```